# Скрыть пустой value в select

Tags: css-selectors

Пытаюсь скрыть скриптом,но что то не хочет

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".form-control #sroc_filter156 option[value='0']").remove();
});
</script>
 
<div class="form-group col-md-12 field ft_unilist f_sroc">
    <label class="clickable"> Тип</label>
        <div id="collapse_sroc" class="collapse show">
             <select class="form-control " name="sroc[]" id="sroc_filter156" multiple="">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="select_all">Выбрать все</option></select>  
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".form-control#sroc_filter156 option[value='']").remove();
               ^^                            ^^
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".form-control#sroc_filter156 option[value='']").remove();
  });
</script>

<div class="form-group col-md-12 field ft_unilist f_sroc">
  <label class="clickable"> Тип</label>
  <div id="collapse_sroc" class="collapse show">
    <select class="form-control " name="sroc[]" id="sroc_filter156" multiple="">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="select_all">Выбрать все</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это работает, на мобильном пока не проверял. Почему айди и класс нужно писать слитно?

Comment: @KoRn потому что это один и тот же элемент

Comment: Понял, на мобильном это тоже работает? Пока не срабатывает, так и висит пустой value, надеюсь что это кеш

Comment: @KoRn Это работает везде.

Comment: У меня стоит библиотека jquery-chosen, но попробую разобраться спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно попробовать:

`<option hidden>Hidden option</option>`

Comment: Мобильный safari игнорирует `display:none` и `hidden` в `option`.